# Segmented control segment images

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

In my project I am using segmented control with 3 segments. I have picture for every segment and pressed/unpressed state. Here is image:

[Image link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/43/testph.png/)

If picture size is not matching segment size then it not fits. Is there any solution for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You can take 3 buttons instead and set images for them and use them as a segmented control if you nedd i can provide you the code

Comment: Solution with 3 buttons should works but I am not sure how to make 3 same buttons which fits every screen size

Comment: well I guess you can set autoResizingMask for all the 3 buttons to make them fit evry screen size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using iOS 5 or later, you can use `UIImage`'s `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` method to create resizable buttons for your segmented control and then just render your text on top of it. A good tutorial on this is available [here](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/ios-5-uiimage-and-resizableimagewithcapinsets.html).

Essentially, all you have to do is create versions of your button images that have distinct ends and centers that can be resized.

Answer (score 0):

Use - (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets method of UIImage for setting image to your button. It will return you resized image for your button. Available in iOS 5.0 and later.

Comment: Well thanks. I tried second method  (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets but I always got same result. The image is too big for segment size and overlap other components. Here is code: 

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Untitled.png"];

image = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 1, 1, 1)];

[self.segmentedControl setImage:image forSegmentAtIndex:0];